# React Native, using RapidAPI inside source code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, security, rapidapi

I used to have this code to retrieve JSON file that has personal data in my React Naive source code:

```
async componentDidMount() {
try {
    const response = await fetch('mydomain.org/personaldata.json');
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson,
    });
}
catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
}
```

Then I decided to used RapidAPI to make it more secure, but I couldn't figure out how to use it and it gives me white page with no data:
This is my modified code:

```
async componentDidMount() {
try {
    const response = await fetch('coin-flip1.p.rapidapi.com/headstails', {
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
          "x-rapidapi-host": "mydomain.org",
          "x-rapidapi-key": 'lkweruytv43578tv3urhgciuyv2b738465873465c87xnb746'
        }
      });
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson,

    });
}
catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
}
```

This is RapidAPI code from their documentation:

```
const fetchData = () => {
startFlip()
setLoading(true);
fetch('https://coin-flip1.p.rapidapi.com/headstails', {
"method": "GET",
"headers": {
  "x-rapidapi-host": "coin-flip1.p.rapidapi.org",
  "x-rapidapi-key": 'apikey'
}
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((json) => setData(json.outcome))
.catch(() => Alert.alert('Something went wrong..', 'There was an error fetching coin flip.'))
.finally(() => {
  setLoading(false)
  resetFlip()
});
};
```

Comment: Check This Blog This Might Help You . https://rapidapi.com/blog/create-react-native-app/

Comment: @BelginAndroid I thought RapidAPI able to underlying my own API request and work as proxy for my own server, but I've found out it has totally different mechanism. Thanks

Comment: you may want to take out your api key fyi

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using [Coin Flip API](https://rapidapi.com/gkbrk/api/coin-flip1/) on RapidAPI. It is working fine for me if I'm using axios.

Try using this code snippet

```
var axios = require("axios").default;

var options = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://coin-flip1.p.rapidapi.com/headstails',
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-key': '12345',
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'coin-flip1.p.rapidapi.com'
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data.outcome);
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```